# Store checkbox checked in coockie JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I create a script that can save checkbox checked and print it out on screen.. But now I need code that will save all clicks on a checkbox in the cookie and in the end it will print it all on the screen.(alert).

Here is code :

```
<input type='checkbox' id='check1' />check1
<input type='checkbox' id='check2' />check2
<input type='checkbox' id='check3' />check3
<input type='checkbox' id='check4' />check4
<input type='button' onclick="test();" value="Test" />


test = function() {
    var checkboxesIDs = '';
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
         if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {  
             if(inputs[i].checked == true) {
                checkboxesIDs+= inputs[i].id +", ";             
             }
         }
    }
    alert(checkboxesIDs);
}
```

Do you have idea how to save all that in cookie...

Comment: there's a plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: hmm ok..Plugin is interesting but I do not understand really. Thank you for your help. I need to study it more. If anyone have some code sample for saving that in cookie that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before your 'alert' statement, add a 'document.cookie' assignment statement to save the string to a cookie.

```
document.cookie = "checkedboxCookie=" + checkboxesIDs;
alert(checkboxesIDs);
```

This will save the string to a cookie named 'checkedboxCookie'.  You can also add expiration to the cookie if you would like.